# How do i get started with CUDA development on UBUNTU 9.04?

Tags: c, cuda, ubuntu-9.04, gpgpu, nvidia

How do i get started with CUDA development on Ubuntu 9.04? Are there any prebuilt binaries? Are the default accelerated drivers sufficient?

My thought is to actually work with OpenCL but that seems to be hard to do right now so i thought that i would start with CUDA and then port my application to OpenCL when that is more readily available.

Comment: 64bit Ubuntu 8.10 is supported ,, does this work well with 9.04?

Comment: Make sure you choose to write your code for the "Low level C" API or Driver API for CUDA if you want to switch to OpenCL later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a blog posting that seems to go through the whole set up: http://lifeofaprogrammergeek.blogspot.com/2008/05/cuda-development-in-ubuntu.html

He uses a different version of Ubuntu, but this should work fine for 9.04.

Answer (score 0):

I found a forum post at the nvidia page and it seems like the 8.10 binaries work well:
http://forums.nvidia.com/lofiversion/index.php?t100839.html